# TypeScript: removing listener for local fat arrow

Tags: typescript

I would like to use a local fat arrow to preserve the *this* context as:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e: KeyboardEvent) => myobject.keyDownlistener(e));
```

And I would like to be able to remove this listener later, but neither of the following work:

```
document.removeEventListener("keydown", (e: KeyboardEvent) => myobject.keyDownlistener(e));
document.removeEventListener("keydown", myobject.keyDownlistener);
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> remove this listener later, but neither of the following work:

Every time you create `()=>` *you create a new function*. So you need to ensure that you *add* and *remove* the *same function*:

```
// What you add
document.addEventListener("keydown", myobject.keyDownlistener);
// Is what you should remove
document.removeEventListener("keydown", myobject.keyDownlistener);
```

To preserve the `this` context make sure `myobject.keyDownlistener` is defined as a fat arrow (instead of a a protoype function)

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for your expert comment. However using instance functions results in a 25% performance hit, as well as you won't be able to call them via the super method. So do I just have to accept that as a compromise ? my rouces:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript
http://athiemann.net/2015/07/19/typescript-class-method-this.html

Comment: You will get the same `25%` hit even if you created the arrow function inline (and not inn the class declration)

Comment: But you are calling the instance method inside the body of your fat arrow, so in reality you just have two function executions instead of one per event. If that doesn't convince you then you can just always save the instance of the fat arrow function in a variable and use it later to remove it as a listener

Comment: well according to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript
that isn't the case, as I would get a different type of a performance hit, but I suppose I will just have to live with it anyhow, as there is no way to remove it otherwise. thanks for the quick and thorough answers!

Answer (score 0):

you can save a reference to the inline function to a variable (or object property as shown in this example) and later pass that into the call to addEventListener

```js
var myobject = {
    keyDownlistener: function (e) {
        if (e.key==="Enter") {
          console.log('you typed',this.msg);
          document.removeEventListener("keydown", myobject.kdl);
        }
        if (!this.msg) this.msg='';
        this.msg += e.key;
    }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", myobject.kdl = (e) => myobject.keyDownlistener(e));
```

```html
Click here then type a message followed by enter
```

if you are happy using an external variable:

```js
var kd,myobject = {
    keyDownlistener: function (e) {
        if (e.key==="Enter") {
          console.log('you typed',this.msg);
          document.removeEventListener("keydown",kd);
        }
        if (!this.msg) this.msg='';
        this.msg += e.key;
    }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", kd = (e) => myobject.keyDownlistener(e));
```

```html
click here and type a line of text
```